# how do i recreate this google plus effect on a place image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-plus

I was just looking at a google plus place and i saw this cool blur effect on an image - the left side of the cover photo, is there anyway to recreate this, i have tried some css blur stuff and a couple plugins although they did not seem to come close to recreating this.

how do you think this is done?

https://plus.google.com/u/0/100447465665053723801/posts

[image: Screenshot]

used:

blur.js 
foggy.js

```
.blur {
-webkit-filter: blur(10px);
-moz-filter: blur(10px);
-o-filter: blur(10px);
-ms-filter: blur(10px);
filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: I've down voted this because the link isn't accessible to me in work so I don't even know what effect you're talking about. Also, you haven't showed us what you have tried that didn't work. If you take a screenshot and post it here, and show us your attempts I'll take away the down-vote.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468038/html-canvas-shape-blur-filter

Comment: @Engineer Dollery do you realy cant open goole profile page? Its public page. user3206729 talk about poster left side. The blured one.

Comment: This question has your answer I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514954/blur-imgs-divs-in-html-using-css

Comment: It's done by [blurring the picture before it even reaches you](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-nvDu86PoiAc/Uzylet0y0CI/AAAAAAAAABE/3mMd0DUauUY/s630-fcrop64=1,00411693ffffee64:Soften=1,60,0/Resort%2BPool%2B-%2Bdusk%2B2.jpg) by the server and not via the client browser.

Answer (score 2):

Google use two copies of the image. One regular and one blurred. They then overlay and clip them.

[image: Blur]

[image: Not blur]

[image: DOM]

Comment: how would i recreate this?

Comment: Blue the image with the photo editing software (or library) of your choice. Then stick the images in containers with fixed dimensions and `overflow: hidden`, then position those containers as you desire.

Comment: i am using the google places api library - javascript, so i would need to do this for the whole world.. so to speak. was looking for script or something

Comment: Nothing stopping you from getting your graphics library of choice (I'd learn towards ImageMagick) and creating a blurred image with it.

Answer (score 0):

They've generated a blurred image version of the header image. Looking at the HTML/CSS you can find the image here:

[https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-nvDu86PoiAc/Uzylet0y0CI/AAAAAAAAABE/3mMd0DUauUY/s630-fcrop64=1,00411693ffffee64:Soften=1,60,0/Resort%2BPool%2B-%2Bdusk%2B2.jpg](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-nvDu86PoiAc/Uzylet0y0CI/AAAAAAAAABE/3mMd0DUauUY/s630-fcrop64=1,00411693ffffee64%3aSoften=1,60,0/Resort%2BPool%2B-%2Bdusk%2B2.jpg)

You can do what you're trying to accomplish using CSS blur however.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; filter: blur(50px);">
        <!-- your image here -->
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <!-- your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, you would not put your CSS inline like that. The image div must be separate otherwise your content will become blurred as well. Also, I should note that there is most likely no way to blur part of an image if that's what you're attempting. You'll need to use the same image twice.