# Circle loading animation

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I'm trying to create Apple's OS X circle loading animation.

[image]

What I have tried so far:

```css
.animation-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.8);
}
.pie-piece1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 100%);
}
.pie-piece2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 1) 100%);
}
.pie-piece3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}
.pie-piece4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}
.rotating-spinners {
  position: absolute;
}
.spike {
  fill: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<figure class="animation-wrapper">
  <div class="pie-piece1"></div>
  <div class="pie-piece2"></div>
  <div class="pie-piece3"></div>
  <div class="pie-piece4"></div>
  <svg class="rotating-spinners" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <path id="spin-part" class="spike" d="M 65,-40 C 65,-40 80,20 50,50 60,40 50,-40 50,-40Z" />
    </defs>
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(60, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(120, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(180, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(240, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(300, 50, 50)" />
  </svg>
</figure>
```

The linear gradients don't seem to line up correctly since i couldn't find a way to make the gradients go in two directions.

Is there a way to create this using only CSS or SVG without mixing them like I have done?

Or are there other solutions I can use like canvas or some kind of image magic?

Comment: Funny fact if you search google "apple loading animation" you can't find it. If you search for "spinning ball of death" you instantly get results.

Comment: I believe it is colloquially called the "spinning beach ball".

Comment: That's sorta what "colloquial" means.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here's my effort. The conical gradient is an embedded bitmap image extracted by calculating the maximum value of each pixel in the animated GIF posted by the OP. A semi-opaque black windmill pattern is superimposed on top of that and animated, and a blur filter gets rid of the JPEG artefacts.

(Edit: Added a reflective highlight to make it look a bit more 3D)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="121" height="121" viewBox="0 0 121 121">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="circ">
      <circle r="60" cx="60.5" cy="60.5"/>
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="shine" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0.6" />
      <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0.3" />
      <stop offset="20%" style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0.1" />
      <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:#fff;stop-opacity:0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image width="121" height="121" filter="url(#blur)" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,
  /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDACAWGBwYFCAcGhwkIiAmMFA0MCwsMGJGSjpQdGZ6eHJm
  cG6AkLicgIiuim5woNqirr7EztDOfJri8uDI8LjKzsb/2wBDASIkJDAqMF40NF7GhHCExsbGxsbG
  xsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsb/wgARCAB5AHkDASEA
  AhEBAxEB/8QAGQAAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECBAMF/8QAGAEAAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEC
  AwT/2gAMAwEAAhADEAAAAfQAXAM9O7YlzoXdLQ5QAIMSL6gA0DS50G6UyRYUyi2NBQhoHMMNzzM2
  VX0BgwKQqSHJDWvTk/McagAMC0TcBUoA9LM8x49ACBjNJlawIlgl0kh8/SIAAekwbYgJiSEUc3WA
  AIdRBrgAhggLOfsAGxVc5xFc6WiBgN08O0AdKbqM551lKuBUjpV1OXWNN0oqohQ84V5pUr3aac8u
  fQ3FOpmnMKXEzWSVLX322WVXD59aamnMEkTNZzehre+ogzLn0p5lEyJzMvN6emmXQAuSIrlunmKX
  E9OhdHswAAAJzQ+tcbnnqtFdSAAD/8QAIBAAAgICAwADAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIAEQMwEBIgIjFAIf/a
  AAgBAQABBQLlsoE+TQIJ1EoTqIUE+SxcoPt3LQLWhluJkKnxkfsR/NRFzG/U8ZWoLsaYXsRj2fah
  6vcG4zv+ipX4CPwH30jCm2qLapkW92NaHDLWxFvyVrUFv2U0BdJ+oODwPrz/AP/EABwRAQACAgMB
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAEAIgETAxIf/aAAgBAwEBPwGvN/Nzox87Hod2O+T8nO+Ud2NkPKYxvHyYNNMa
  Ji8OjGB9sbYwNOegp0//xAAfEQABBAMAAwEAAAAAAAAAAAABAAIRIBAwMQMSIUH/2gAIAQIBAT8B
  pKI0BOEaD9Gk0CGX9oEMkTRugOheylTUoFTcUPajAT9DhIsz7l4irRAyRKc0jLGfpq/mPH2n/8QA
  HhAAAQQBBQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEQEgITAQAAJAUHD/2gAIAQEABj8CzFEvCVDc0JYFyPADceljUvni
  /wD/xAAdEAADAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAREQMSAhQTBh/9oACAEBAAE/Ic9R2Y3vcR6iHh+A2+Hi
  6LrdR1PR8m0lWNfEVtvFLilwnTpnggTTVXBnhCpClKUpSlKKUd4+evbYkRSlKUpSlKUSq+nRvaxY
  ZSlKUpSlKUpSC/GTlSlKUpSlLi5VypRvnOcKn0QhBInWCEJyhMQglhBomJiFFREIQgkLDGhomZiJ
  JI2sQSIImGhog0Qh3DbzbVrMEuDRCYrr1waqjHa6FzYxz96EoouXp0O1oLgzt6R69vlPZrl7zv/a
  AAwDAQACAAMAAAAQCZ9GgAVrOID+MKOo0R0OMKN+ec1rZcb1FaGkEgox777+BDUwvvfOejgbCEVt
  p82ChkNz+AVXCzANstqAAEMAAP/EABoRAAMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABERAgITH/2gAIAQMBAT8Q
  Eq4eeENso1wlHa1j9Jj4SVrGXUokiEHh4iExjansPgb0pS8SwvLPQkZSixjwvurR6g+C8UeEHh8S
  RTAYx7W1ZDHhCS1OMVDGJc/XT//EABsRAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAEAERAhMSBh/9oACAECAQE/
  EOHlsItTT9kstHnGIiODw4/eERZEMU6PAs4PrpyO+S3mz1vlttvdiWwXtvNtlzINvNlllDDDt5my
  ywyhvmGOyy2wwwwYcBZbYYYa7u/ktsMfjCGMz7w98s/0D9/J/8QAIxABAAICAgICAgMAAAAAAAAA
  AQARECExQSBRMGGhsXGBkf/aAAgBAQABPxDCgWxl/q4naJ0QW2rDhCfVnIGK21QfaF0xz/bgiWeL
  pKCIXTuzfbRYZLyX7mygIbujDSWOVotlzdeX3KUc/EAKA8y1W3DBssxuGW2eX4AL4dpnCbP68Khw
  NHixgcD4sUjkpn3zhfcvwBJDDgcV4K6rkl/UVS5cuXLhDpgtwMuEduFeFSmWl1yKOZUqVKm5WKlS
  sCCbXiB6Sh4jLgrwrJULQ6E6IFFZVisKw/mjdRdmQgjsglQalmFiokfqrtn1zQkAvwAwiomBwGGk
  1BgSymPWb/iBAhgBKlYGGEiCWv5gUUZJgsY7e36ylagQIEqJEggqXoV+8IgoPFBKYS229RtpD7jH
  hIYYg5SFtM/cMbbeoFFHwc04MnGHKcXl/9k=" clip-path="url(#circ)" />
  <g transform="translate(60.5,60.5)">
    <path d="M0 0A56 56 0 0 0 0 56 56 56 0 0 0 32.916 45.305 56 56 0 0 1 0 0 56
        56 0 0 0 53.259 17.305 56 56 0 0 0 53.259-17.305 56 56 0 0 1 0 0 56 56
        0 0 0 32.916-45.305 56 56 0 0 0 0-56 56 56 0 0 1 0 0 56 56 0 0 0
        -32.916-45.305 56 56 0 0 0-53.259-17.305 56 56 0 0 1 0 0 56 56 0 0 0
        -53.259 17.305 56 56 0 0 0-32.916 45.305 56 56 0 0 1 0 0Z"
        stroke="none" fill="#000" opacity="0.25" transform="rotate(0)">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0"
          to="72" begin="0s" dur="0.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>
    <circle r="59" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="none" opacity="0.25" />
    <circle r="55" fill="url(#shine)" stroke="none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I just noticed that Apple's original beachball only has five spokes, so I've updated the SVG.

Answer (score 71):

Here's my SVG-only version.  The background colour wheel isn't perfect, but I think I got fairly close.

```html
<svg width="135" height="135" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur" color-interpolation-filters="linear">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="11"/>
        </filter>
        <mask id="mask">
            <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="90" fill="white"/>
        </mask>
        <linearGradient id="gloss" x2="0" y2="0.4">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <g transform="translate(100,100)" mask="url(#mask)">
        <g filter="url(#blur)">
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#c44"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#c09" transform="rotate(30)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#c0c" transform="rotate(60)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#90c" transform="rotate(90)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#44c" transform="rotate(120)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#09c" transform="rotate(150)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#0cc" transform="rotate(180)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#0c9" transform="rotate(210)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#4c4" transform="rotate(240)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#9c0" transform="rotate(270)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#cc0" transform="rotate(300)"/>
            <polygon points="0,0, -100,-26.8, -100,26.8" fill="#c90" transform="rotate(330)"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="scale(0.9,0.9)">
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(60)"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(120)"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(180)"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(240)"/>
            <path d="M0,0C5,-61,-32,-86,-95,-90L-100,-46C-65,-53,-24,-35,0,0Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.4" transform="rotate(300)"/>
            <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>

        </g>
        <circle r="83" fill="url(#gloss)"/>
        <circle r="90" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could it be a missing CSS vendor prefix that chrome required in v38 but doesn't any longer? Works for me too, Chrome 43.

Comment: Whoever designed the original has tinkered with the gradient. The red area of the circle is bigger than the green and blue parts.  So, for instance, the yellow is pushed further around to where the green should be.  I could get it closer to the original, but I just went with equal sector sizes.

Comment: If it's missing completely, it is almost certainly something it doesn't like with the filter.  Maybe try removing the `color-interpolation-filters`...

Comment: I'm not seeing colors either, but I'm on Firefox 38.

Comment: Whoops. Silly typo on my part. Should be fixed now. It's a wonder it worked on Chrome at all.

Comment: Nice solution. I really like how you blur lines to create the gradients.

Comment: I like your approach. I am keen to learn svg. Can you please tell me what you have used to generate the svg design? if you did all by yourself, please ignore.

Answer (score 56):

**Canvas Approach**

Since this is a loading animation where the dimensions are probably going to be fixed with almost nil user interactions, **Canvas would also be a good option** because it doesn't add any extra elements to the DOM. Canvas drawing commands are pretty similar to SVG and the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/canvas) is also not worse.

One disadvantage would be that Canvas does not have its own blur filter (unlike SVG). But that can be overcome by either using CSS blur filter (has very low browser support) or the libraries mentioned in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468038/html-canvas-shape-blur-filter).

---

**Background Gradient Wheel:**

The background gradient wheel is created using an approach similar to the one detailed in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729543/creating-a-new-spiky-label-with-24-or-above-point-burst/30892219#30892219). Basically we find multiple points in the circle and draw lines each of which have different colored stroke. By modifying the `hue` value for every line we can paint the gradient wheel.

In the below screenshot the first picture shows how the background would have looked if we had drawn just 24 lines (with a `hue` change of 15 between every line)and the  second one is our actual gradient wheel which has 360 lines in total with the `hue` being incremented by 1 for each line.

[image]

**Fan:**

The fan is created using the same approach as used in your SVG snippet. Path commands are used to draw each spoke. While `use` tag is used in SVG to repeat a shape, loops can be used in Canvas.

The main difference here between SVG and Canvas is that Canvas cannot take in transform origin as a parameter for the `rotate` function and so context must be translated to the center point before applying rotations.

Finally the canvas must be clipped into a circle because the default shape is a square (as height and width are same). The below screenshot shows the unclipped and clipped versions of the fan.

[image]

This fan is then placed on top of the background gradient wheel.

**3D effect:**

The 3D effect on top is provided by adding a small arc with an higher amount of transparency over the background and the fan.

Below is the screenshot of the full picture without any animation.

[image]

**Animation:**

Animation is added by using the [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) method which calls the function passed as an argument at regular intervals. This method would generally call the function about 60 times per second (according to MDN). By incrementing the value of the `counter` variable during every iteration and adding it to the angle of the fan's spokes the animation effect can be achieved.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    counter = 360;

  function fan() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    for (var i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + (180 - i) + ", 60%, 50%)";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
      x = 50 + 50 * Math.cos((i / 360) * Math.PI * 2);
      y = 50 + 50 * Math.sin((i / 360) * Math.PI * 2)
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    counter++;
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.clip();
      ctx.translate(50, 50);
      ctx.rotate(((60 * j) + counter) * Math.PI / 180);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(0, 0, 30, 50, 100, 0);
      x = 75 * Math.cos((-20 / 360) * Math.PI * 2);
      y = 75 * Math.sin((-20 / 360) * Math.PI * 2)
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, y, (x - 30), (y + 40), 0, 0);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.restore();
    }
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI, true);
    ctx.arc(50, 55, 50, Math.PI, 0, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.15)";
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(fan);
  }
  fan();
}
```

```html
<canvas width='100px' height='100px' id='canvas'></canvas>
```

---

**SVG Approach**

The same approach as described above can be used with SVG also. The only downside would be the no. of extra elements that get added to the DOM both for the background and the fan.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var colorWheel = document.querySelector("#color-wheel");
  for (var i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
    lineColor = "hsl(" + (180 - i) + ", 60%, 50%)";
    x = 50 + 50 * Math.cos((i / 360) * Math.PI * 2);
    y = 50 + 50 * Math.sin((i / 360) * Math.PI * 2);
    line = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
    line.setAttribute('x1', 50);
    line.setAttribute('y1', 50);
    line.setAttribute('x2', x);
    line.setAttribute('y2', y);
    line.setAttribute('stroke', lineColor);
    line.setAttribute('stroke-width', 2);
    colorWheel.appendChild(line);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="rotating-spinners" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="spin-part" class="spike" d="M 50,50 c0,0 30,50 100,0 l-5,-35 c0,0 -30,50 -95,35Z" />
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="shade">
      <path d='M-5,55 a55,55 1 0,1 110,0 h-5 a50,50 1 0,0 -100,0' />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id='color-wheel' clip-path='url(#shape)'>
  </g>
  <g id='fan' fill-opacity="0.5" clip-path='url(#shape)'>
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(60, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(120, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(180, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(240, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(300, 50, 50)" />
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0,50,50" to="360,50,50" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </g>
  <circle r='50' cx='50' cy='50' fill-opacity='0.15' clip-path='url(#shade)' />
</svg>
```

---

**Mixed Approach**

Or, if you have no problems with the extra elements for the fan but just want to avoid the 360 `line` elements that would get added, you could use a mixture of Canvas (for the background) and SVG for the fans like in the below snippet.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  for (var i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "hsl(" + (180 - i) + ", 60%, 50%)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
    x = 50 + 50 * Math.cos((i / 360) * Math.PI * 2);
    y = 50 + 50 * Math.sin((i / 360) * Math.PI * 2)
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI, true);
  ctx.arc(50, 55, 50, Math.PI, 0, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.15)";
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
canvas,
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <canvas width='100px' height='100px' id='canvas'></canvas>
  <svg class="rotating-spinners" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <path id="spin-part" class="spike" d="M 50,50 c0,0 30,50 100,0 l-5,-35 c0,0 -30,50 -95,35Z" />
      <clipPath id="shape">
        <circle r="50" cx="50" cy="50" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g id='fan' fill-opacity="0.5" clip-path="url(#shape)">
      <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" />
      <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(60, 50, 50)" />
      <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(120, 50, 50)" />
      <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(180, 50, 50)" />
      <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(240, 50, 50)" />
      <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(300, 50, 50)" />
      <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0,50,50" to="360,50,50" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

I had to do this with a mixture of SVG and CSS gradients which i know is against the request but is what i know. I used some of your original code, mostly the SVG parts for the propeller shapes.

The radial gradient is made using 12 `li` elements.

```css
.wheel,
.umbrella,
.color {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wheel {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  position: relative;
}
.umbrella {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
}
.color,
.color:nth-child(n+7):after {
  clip: rect(0, 15em, 15em, 7.5em);
}
.color:after,
.color:nth-child(n+7) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  top: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  clip: rect(0, 7.5em, 15em, 0);
}
.color:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #9ED110;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 12;
}
.color:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #50B517;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 11;
}
.color:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #179067;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 10;
}
.color:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: #476EAF;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 9;
}
.color:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: #9f49ac;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  z-index: 8;
}
.color:nth-child(6):after {
  background-color: #CC42A2;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 7;
}
.color:nth-child(7):after {
  background-color: #FF3BA7;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.color:nth-child(8):after {
  background-color: #FF5800;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.color:nth-child(9):after {
  background-color: #FF8100;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.color:nth-child(10):after {
  background-color: #FEAC00;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.color:nth-child(11):after {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.color:nth-child(12):after {
  background-color: #EDE604;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wheel">
  <ul class="umbrella">
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

These 12 elements can then be blurred together to form the smooth gradient.

I then animated the spin parts to make the effect you require.

```js
var rotation = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    rotation += 1;
    $('.wheel svg').css({
      'transform': 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)'
    });;
  }, 10);
});
```

```css
.wheel,
.umbrella,
.color {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wheel {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  position: relative;
}
.umbrella {
  position: relative;
  filter: blur(.75em);
  -webkit-filter: blur(.75em);
  -moz-filter: blur(.75em);
  -o-filter: blur(.75em);
  -ms-filter: blur(.75em);
  filter: url(#blur);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='.75');
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
}
.color,
.color:nth-child(n+7):after {
  clip: rect(0, 15em, 15em, 7.5em);
}
.color:after,
.color:nth-child(n+7) {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  top: calc(50% - 7.5em);
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  clip: rect(0, 7.5em, 15em, 0);
}
.color:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #9ED110;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 12;
}
.color:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #50B517;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 11;
}
.color:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #179067;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 10;
}
.color:nth-child(4):after {
  background-color: #476EAF;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  z-index: 9;
}
.color:nth-child(5):after {
  background-color: #9f49ac;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  z-index: 8;
}
.color:nth-child(6):after {
  background-color: #CC42A2;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 7;
}
.color:nth-child(7):after {
  background-color: #FF3BA7;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.color:nth-child(8):after {
  background-color: #FF5800;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.color:nth-child(9):after {
  background-color: #FF8100;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.color:nth-child(10):after {
  background-color: #FEAC00;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.color:nth-child(11):after {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.color:nth-child(12):after {
  background-color: #EDE604;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
body {
  padding: 5px;
}
.wheel svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="animation-wrapper wheel">
  <ul class="umbrella">
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
    <li class="color"></li>
  </ul>
  <svg class="rotating-spinners" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <path id="spin-part" class="spike" d="M 65,-40 C 65,-40 80,20 50,50 60,40 50,-40 50,-40Z" />
    </defs>
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(60, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(120, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(180, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(240, 50, 50)" />
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#spin-part" transform="rotate(300, 50, 50)" />
  </svg>
</figure>
```

- [Conical CSS Gradient](https://css-tricks.com/conical-gradients-css/)

Comment: In the current version of firefox, that displays odd.

Comment: In my version of chrome it looks pretty off too. Very light.

Comment: Well, I *like* how it renders with IE11, even if it's *really* odd and broken.

Comment: @Deduplicator Firefox 38.0.5 and 39.0 (with GPU acceleration disabled) and Internet Explorer 11 (with GPU acceleration disabled) show exactly the same way. This is simply broken. On Google Chrome, the whole thing looks weird and the color stops are messed up. Also, this doesn't come that close to the required version.

Comment: @Deduplicator looks kind of like a fan slicing a rainbow pie

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure CSS solution where I will consider the use of only **one** element. I will rely on the shape I created [in this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159993/8620333) and above I will consider a [`conic-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient).

Actually the `conic-gradient()` is only supported in Chrome and Safari but we will soon have better support:

```css
.box {
  --R:50px; /*Radius*/
  --c1:grey; /*first color*/
  --c2:#fff; /*second color*/
  
  --g1:var(--c1) 98%, transparent 100%;
  --g2:var(--c2) 98%, transparent 100%;
  width:calc(2*var(--R));
  height:calc(2*var(--R));
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  background:conic-gradient(rgba(128, 0, 128,0.7), rgba(0, 0, 255,0.7),rgba(0, 128, 0,0.7),rgba(255, 255, 0,0.7), rgba(255, 0, 0,0.7), rgba(128, 0, 128,0.7));
  box-shadow:0 3px 5px inset rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
  background:
     /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5xR   
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866xR 
     */
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at var(--R)                        0                              ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at 0                               var(--R)                        ,var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1));   
    transform-origin:right;
    animation:animate 3s linear infinite;
}

/*the same shape rotated*/
.box::after {
   animation-delay:-1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    transform:rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Output

[image]

Here is in the other direction (like your animation)

```css
.box {
  --R:50px; /*Radius*/
  --c1:grey; /*first color*/
  --c2:#fff; /*second color*/
  
  --g1:var(--c1) 98%, transparent 100%;
  --g2:var(--c2) 98%, transparent 100%;
  width:calc(2*var(--R));
  height:calc(2*var(--R));
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  background:conic-gradient(rgba(128, 0, 128,0.7), rgba(0, 0, 255,0.7),rgba(0, 128, 0,0.7),rgba(255, 255, 0,0.7), rgba(255, 0, 0,0.7), rgba(128, 0, 128,0.7));
  box-shadow:0 3px 5px inset rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
  background:
     /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5xR   
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866xR 
     */
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at var(--R)                        0                              ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at 0                               var(--R)                        ,var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1));   
    transform-origin:right;
    animation:animate 3s linear infinite;
}

/*the same shape rotated*/
.box::after {
   animation-delay:-1.5s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform:scale(-1,1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:scale(-1,1) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot to the answer, looks really good. Did not know of the conic-gradient before today.

Comment: @Persijn added screenshot