# How to create a lollipop shape by stacking divs in a circular manner?

Tags: css, sass, css-transforms, css-shapes

How to stack divs in a circular manner in which last div should come beneath the first div but above the second last div. Is it possible with the css? any helps would be appreciated.

[image]

Please find the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/vivekraj_kr/pen/VRyKNR).
Giving the sample code snippet

```
<div class="frame">
  <div class="lolly-pop__wrapper">
    <div class="lollypop-top">
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.frame {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F5CE51;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.lollypop-top {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    .lollypop-top__item {
        position: absolute;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        top: -50%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        transform-origin: bottom;
        background-color: #fff;

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #D70606;
        }

        &:nth-child(1) {
            transform: rotate(30deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
            transform: rotate(60deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(3) {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(4) {
            transform: rotate(120deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(5) {
            transform: rotate(150deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(6) {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(7) {
            transform: rotate(210deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(8) {
            transform: rotate(240deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(9) {
            transform: rotate(270deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(10) {
            transform: rotate(300deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(11) {
            transform: rotate(330deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(12) {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F5CE51;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.lollypop-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: -50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #D70606;
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

.lollypop-top .lollypop-top__item:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="lolly-pop__wrapper">
    <div class="lollypop-top">
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
      <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's only about the final visual?

Comment: you need to give each lollypop item its own positioning...... so #1 top:0; left:0; #2 top:50; left:50; and so on and so on. Currently you have them all stack on top of each other

Comment: why don't you just create and .svg image and embed the code?

Comment: @Moose Can you pls post it as an answer with jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: @TemaniAfif  I'm planning to animate it.

Comment: @Bertlucas If it's possible with css that would be fantastic.

Comment: Just to clarify, which of these are you trying to do? 1) http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/42900/42913/circle-19_42913_md.gif     OR 2) something like this -   https://giphy.com/gifs/pizza-loading-snacks-3o7bu8sRnYpTOG1p8k

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would create this considering two elements (pseudo elements) and multiple radial gradient. You only need to create half the shape twice and rotate one of them.

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  background:
    /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5x75px   = 37.5px 
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866x75px = 64.95px       
       10.05px = 75px - 64.95px;
       112.5px = 75px + 37.5px
       139.95px = 75px + 64.95px
       37.5px = 75px - 37.5px
       */
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 139.95px 37.5px,red   98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 112.5px 10.05px,white 98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 75px    0,      red   98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 37.5px  10.05px,white 98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 10.05px 37.5px ,red   98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 0       75px,   white 98%,transparent 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle 75px at 10.05px 112.5px,red   98%,transparent 100%);
}

.box::after {
 transform:rotate(180deg);
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

[image: CSS lollipop shape]

To make things more funny we can add CSS variables to easily control the shape:

```css
.box {
  --R:50px; /*Radius*/
  --c1:red; /*first color*/
  --c2:#fff; /*second color*/
  
  --g1:var(--c1) 98%, transparent 100%;
  --g2:var(--c2) 98%, transparent 100%;
  width:calc(2*var(--R));
  height:calc(2*var(--R));
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  background:
     /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5xR   
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866xR 
     */
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at var(--R)                        0                              ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))   calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)),var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) - 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at 0                               var(--R)                        ,var(--g2)),
    radial-gradient(circle var(--R) at calc(var(--R) - 0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R) + 0.5*var(--R))  ,var(--g1));
}

/*the same shape rotated*/
.box::after {
 transform:rotate(180deg);
 transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:80px;--c1:blue"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:100px;--c1:green;--c2:yellow"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:150px;--c1:white;--c2:pink"></div>
```

---

Note that Safari doesn't support the syntax with `at` (explained here [How to make radial gradients work in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299171/8620333)) so here is anothe syntax:

```css
.box {
  --R:50px;  /*Radius*/
  --c1:red;  /*first color*/
  --c2:#fff; /*second color*/
  
  width:calc(2*var(--R));
  height:calc(2*var(--R));
  border-radius:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.box::before,
.box::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset: 0 50% 0 0;
  --g1:radial-gradient(50% 50%,var(--c1) 98%, #0000);
  --g2:radial-gradient(50% 50%,var(--c2) 98%, #0000);
  background:
     /*we rotate by 30deg so will use :
       sin(30deg)*R = 0.5xR   
       cos(30deg)*R = 0.866xR 
     */
    var(--g1) calc(0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R)/-2), 
    var(--g2) calc(var(--R)/2) calc(-0.866*var(--R)),
    var(--g1) 0 calc(-1*var(--R)),
    var(--g2) calc(var(--R)/-2) calc(-0.866*var(--R)),
    var(--g1) calc(-0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R)/-2),
    var(--g2) calc(-1*var(--R)) 0,
    var(--g1) calc(-0.866*var(--R)) calc(var(--R)/2);
   background-size:calc(2*var(--R)) calc(2*var(--R));
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

/*the same shape rotated*/
.box::after {
 transform:rotate(180deg);
 transform-origin:right center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:80px;--c1:blue"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:100px;--c1:green;--c2:yellow"></div>

<div class="box" style="--R:150px;--c1:white;--c2:pink"></div>
```

[image: multicolor lollipop shape CSS]

Here is a [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/RwwzgXo) demo to play with the code

Answer (score 8):

My approach would be a reusable SVG `<symbol>`, with paths shaped by *quadratic-bézier* curves:

```css
#svg-lollipop path { transform-origin: 50% 50%; }

#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(2) {  transform: rotateZ(60deg); }
#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(3) {  transform: rotateZ(120deg); }
#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(4) {  transform: rotateZ(180deg); }
#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(5) {  transform: rotateZ(240deg); }
#svg-lollipop path:nth-child(6) {  transform: rotateZ(300deg); }

.lollipop {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 20px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.lollipop svg {
  position: absolute;  
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.lollipop--animated {
  animation: rotate 10s linear 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotateZ(0) }
  100% { transform: rotateZ(1turn) }
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;">
   <symbol id="svg-lollipop">
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
      <path d="M150,150 Q75,185 0,150 H0 V63.6 Q75,150 150,150 z" />
   </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="lollipop lollipop--animated" 
  style="background-color: #FFF; color:#E92120;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300"><use xlink:href="#svg-lollipop"></use></svg>
</div>

<div class="lollipop" 
  style="background-color: #004991; color:#007BC1;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 300 300"><use xlink:href="#svg-lollipop"></use></svg>
</div>
```

---

**How it works**

The same shape was cloned 6 times and rotated in order to fill the whole svg. In this example, every coloured shape has an angle `α = 30deg`.

Then from trigonometry we can find the coordinates of the origin points for the curves: in the path the *y-coordinate* `63.6` is obtained as `150 - (150 * tan(α))`, so if you need to change the amount of shapes and the angle, you can easily find yourself the origin points ([quadratic curves](https://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-paths-curve-commands/) are really easy to draw).

Finally, the outer wrapper has a `border-radius` and a hidden `overflow` in order to give a rounded shape.

[image]

---

The final result is also responsive, since the outer wrapper keeps its `1:1` aspect ratio.

The white area can be changed with a `background-color` set on the container, the coloured area can be changed instead with the `color` property (the `fill` property of the `svg` elements is set to `currentColor` for your convenience).

---

**something I've noticed later**

if you add a `box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #aaa;` to the wrapper the image  looks like an inflatable beach balloon than a lollipop.

Serendipity.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this answer as well.[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vivekraj_kr/pen/VRyKNR)

```
<div class="frame">
<div class="lolly-pop__wrapper">
<div class="lollypop-top">
    <div class="first__half">
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="second__half">
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
        <div class="lollypop-top__item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


.frame {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F5CE51;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.lollypop-top {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

.lollypop-top__item {
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    top: -50%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    background-color: #fff;

    &:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #D70606;
    }

    &:nth-child(1) {
        transform: rotate(30deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
        transform: rotate(60deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(4) {
        transform: rotate(120deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(5) {
        transform: rotate(150deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(6) {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(7) {
        transform: rotate(210deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(8) {
        transform: rotate(240deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(9) {
        transform: rotate(270deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(10) {
        transform: rotate(300deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(11) {
        transform: rotate(330deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(12) {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(13) {
        transform: rotate(390deg);
    }

    &:nth-child(14) {
        transform: rotate(420deg);
    }
  }
}

.first__half,
.second__half {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.first__half {
    width: 50%;
}

.second__half {
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin:right center;
}
```