# SVG gradient color

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

Hi I'm working with SVG here I trying to add the gradient to SVG like this
[image]

white and grey gradient but I unable to achieve the desired output. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <defs>  
   <linearGradient id="GradientRepeat" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0" spreadMethod="repeat">
      <stop offset="0.05" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#777" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
   </defs>
    <circle class="sub-menu-circle" cx="0" cy="200" r="160" fill="url(#GradientRepeat)" />
 </svg>
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 700" class="bubble-svg">
 <defs>

  <linearGradient id="GradientRepeat" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0" spreadMethod="repeat" gradientTransform="rotate(170)">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
   <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#bdbdbd" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
   <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
   <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#bdbdbd" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
   <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
   <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#bdbdbd" stop-opacity="1"/>

   <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
   <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#bdbdbd" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
   <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#bdbdbd" stop-opacity="0"/>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fbfbfb" stop-opacity="0.5"/>

  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <circle class="sub-menu-circle" cx="0" cy="200" r="160" fill="url(#GradientRepeat)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: why don't you just add more intermediate color stops?

Comment: @Michael Mullany, I had tried by adding multiple color stops but I didn't get the output

Comment: @RobertLongson I updated my question.

Comment: This does what you want (well - you need to tweak the colors and the x2 - but basically it works (at least in Chrome/Windows). What's wrong with this?

Comment: @ Michael Mullany, I'm trying to achieve exactly shown in the image color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fine-tuning the rendering of shades of gray and white colors depends on which video card, browser and operating system you are using.

Therefore, I am sending several options. You can use any option that you prefer or slightly adjust for yourself by changing the colors.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 700" class="bubble-svg">
 <defs>

  <linearGradient id="GradientRepeat" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" spreadMethod="repeat" gradientTransform="rotate(170)">
  
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#B4B4B5" stop-opacity="1"/>
   <stop offset="17%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
   
   <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#B4B4B5" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
   <stop offset="49%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
   
   <stop offset="61%" stop-color="#B4B4B5" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
   <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
    <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#B4B4B5" stop-opacity="1"/>
 
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <circle class="sub-menu-circle" cx="0" cy="200" r="160" fill="url(#GradientRepeat)" />
</svg>
```

2#  variant

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 700" class="bubble-svg">
 <defs>

  <linearGradient id="GradientRepeat" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" spreadMethod="repeat" gradientTransform="rotate(170)">
  
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#B4B4B5" stop-opacity="1"/>
   <stop offset="17%" stop-color="#F6F6F6" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
   
   <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#B4B4B5" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
   <stop offset="49%" stop-color="#F6F6F6" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
   
   <stop offset="61%" stop-color="#B4B4B5" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
   <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#F6F6F6" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
    
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#B4B4B5" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <circle class="sub-menu-circle" cx="0" cy="200" r="160" fill="url(#GradientRepeat)" />
</svg>
```

3#  variant

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 700" class="bubble-svg">
 <defs>

  <linearGradient id="GradientRepeat" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" spreadMethod="repeat" gradientTransform="rotate(170)">
  
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ABABAC" stop-opacity="1"/>
   <stop offset="17%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
   
   <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ABABAC" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
   <stop offset="49%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
   
   <stop offset="61%" stop-color="#ABABAC" stop-opacity="0.6"/>
   <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
   
   
   <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#ABABAC" stop-opacity="1"/>

  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <circle class="sub-menu-circle" cx="0" cy="200" r="160" fill="url(#GradientRepeat)" />
</svg>
```

For a more precise adjustment to your taste, it is better to use `stop-color` and `stop-opacity` choosing values.

**Update**

For the method `spreadMethod ="repeat"` to start working in your example, you need to reduce the gradient coverage by three times. To do this, set `x1 ="0" y1 ="0" x2 ="0" y2 ="0.33"`
As a result, adjusting the color tones of one wave, we get completely identical copies of it, which facilitates the process compared to the option of a large number of `stop-offset`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 700" class="bubble-svg">
 <defs>

  <linearGradient id="GradientRepeat" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0.33" 
     spreadMethod="repeat"  gradientTransform="rotate(170)">
  
   <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#ABABAC" stop-opacity="1"/>
   <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ffffff" stop-opacity="0.8"/>
   <stop offset="85%" stop-color="#ABABAC" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <circle class="sub-menu-circle" cx="0" cy="200" r="160" fill="url(#GradientRepeat)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort.